# Submit button doesn't work in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-thymeleaf

I have MVC project on Spring Boot that suppose to do CRUD operations. Basically it has two models, which represents Forum Theme and Article of this Theme. And I want to add new Themes or Articles. Now I stuck on submitting form data, managed with POST request.
My controller:

```
@Controller
public class forumController {

    @Autowired
    private themeRepository themeRepository;

    @Autowired
    private articleRepository articleRepository;

    @GetMapping("/forum")
    public String blogMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<ThemeModel> themes = themeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("themes", themes);
        return "blogMain";
    }

    @GetMapping("/guest")
    public String guestMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<ThemeModel> themes = themeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("themes", themes);
        return "blogMain";
    }

    @GetMapping("/guest/{id}")
    public String readTheme(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model) {
        Optional<ThemeModel> theme = themeRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<ThemeModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
        theme.ifPresent(result::add);
        model.addAttribute("theme", result);
        return "readTheme";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public String userMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<ThemeModel> themes = themeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("themes", themes);
        return "userMain";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public String userReadTheme(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model) {
        Optional<ThemeModel> theme = themeRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<ThemeModel> result = new ArrayList<>();
        theme.ifPresent(result::add);
        model.addAttribute("theme", result);
        return "userReadTheme";
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/addArticle/{id}")
    public String userAddArticle(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, Model model) {

        return "userAddArticle";
    }

    @PostMapping("/user/addArticle/{id}")
    public String userAddArticlePost(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id, @RequestParam String full_text, Model model) {
        ArticleModel article = new ArticleModel(full_text);
        articleRepository.save(article);
        ThemeModel thisTheme = themeRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
        thisTheme.getArticles().add(article);
        themeRepository.save(thisTheme);

        return "redirect:/user/{id}";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminMain(Model model) {
        Iterable<ThemeModel> themes = themeRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("themes", themes);
        return "adminMain";
    }

    @GetMapping("/admin/addTheme")
    public String addTheme(Model model) {
        return "adminAddTheme";
    }

    @PostMapping("/admin/addTheme")
    public String addPostTheme(@RequestParam("heading") String heading, @RequestParam("description") String description, Model model) {

        ThemeModel theme = new ThemeModel(heading, description);
        themeRepository.save(theme);

        return "redirect:/admin";
    }
}
```

Template to add theme:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="text-muted p-2 mt-1">Додати нову тему</h1>
<div class="container mt-5">
    <th:taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" />
    <form:form action="#" th:action="@{/admin/addTheme}" th:object="${theme}" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="heading" placeholder="Введіть заголовок..." class="form-control mb-2"/>
        <input type="text" name="description" placeholder="Введіть опис..." class="form-control mb-2"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Опублікувати" class="btn btn-info mt-2"/>
    </form:form>
    <a href="/admin" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Скасувати</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Template to add Article:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-muted p-2 mt-1">Додати допис</h1>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <th:taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" />
        <form:form method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
            <textarea name="full_text" placeholder="Введіть текст" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mt-2">Опублікувати</button>
            <a href="/user" class="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Скасувати</a>
        </form:form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Theme Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "themes")
public class ThemeModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String heading, description;

    public ThemeModel() {

    }

    public ThemeModel(String heading, String description) {
        this.heading = heading;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    List<ArticleModel> articles = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<ArticleModel> getArticles() {
        return articles;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setHeading(String heading) {
        this.heading = heading;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setArticles(List<ArticleModel> articles) {
        this.articles = articles;
    }
}
```

Article Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="articles")
public class ArticleModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String full_text;

    public ArticleModel() {

    }

    public ArticleModel(String full_text) {
        super();
        this.full_text = full_text;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFull_text() {
        return full_text;
    }

    public void setFull_text(String full_text) {
        this.full_text = full_text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: Form submission is not happening at all. And I get no errors.

Comment: You are using `th:taglib` and `form:form` which I have never seen in the context of Thymeleaf. Are you sure that is ok? Where did you get that information from? Can you try with a simple `<form>` tag? See [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/) for some background on form submission with Thymeleaf.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you. th:taglib and form:form caused the trouble, now it works as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the use of `th:taglib` and `form:form` and use a normal HTML `<form>`.